# apply a function on list values from dictionary and make a new dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary where values are in shape of a list.

```
entities = {"CAMERA": ["camera"], "DISPLAY": ["display", "bild"], "AKKU": ["akku", "battery"]}
```

I want to iterate through all items in each list and apply a function to each of those items. Then I want to add the resulting values to my `new_dict` such that

`new_dict = {"CAMERA": [0.1], "DISPLAY": [0.55, 0.2]}`

where 0.55 and 0.22 are values returned by `myFunction`for each item in the list.

```
def checkValue(value):
    new_dict = {}
    #for key, value in entities:
        result = myFunction((key), (value))
        new_dict[i] = result
```

How can I do so in a readable manner?

Comment: Is the only input to the function just a value from list such as "camera"?

Comment: `{k: [checkValue(i) for i in v] for k, v in entities.items()}`

Comment: Yes, the list values are passed as a parameter to the function @DarrylG

Comment: @a125--then the comment in OlvinRoght answer should work, where checkValue is the function you apply.

Comment: is it also possible to extract the key of the max values across all lists? ```{'CAMERA': [0.0], 'DISPLAY': [0.12, 0.0], 'AKKU': [0.5, 0.0]}``` in a similar fashion? @DarrylG AKKU in this case.

Comment: @a125.  If `new_dict` is the new dictionary, then key with max value is: `max(new_dict, key = lambda x: max(new_dict[x]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having the opportunity to test your full code, I would say:

```
def checkValue(value):
    new_dict = {}
    for key, values in entities.items():
        new_dict[key] = []
        for value in values:
            result = myFunction(key, value)
            new_dict[key].append(result)
            #or directly new_dict[key].append(myFunction(key, value))
```

Comment: is it also possible to extract the key of the max values across all lists? ```{'CAMERA': [0.0], 'DISPLAY': [0.12, 0.0], 'AKKU': [0.5, 0.0]}``` in a similar fashion?

Comment: Again, without having tested your full code I can propose this:
`for key, values in new_dict.items():
 if not saved or max(values) > max(new_dict[saved]):
  saved = key`
(sorry for the poor indentation of the code in the comment)